# Video não aparece quando faço Build do projeto

Tags: html, react

Criei um site usando ReactJS, e na parte inicial eu coloquei um video de fundo e um texto na frente, quando abro o site ReactJs na minha maquina o video aparece normalmente sem nenhum problema, quando dou deploy no site para o Heroku, tudo esta funcionando normalmente menos a o video que não aparece.
Tanto o video quando as imagens que estão no site estão nos mesmo diretorio, e apenas o video que não aparece.

Deescobri quando dou Build no meu projeto, o video tambem nao aparece na minha maquina.

```
npm run build
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

Imagens de exemplo:

[image: O video é essa logo da apple de fundo, na mihna maquina aparece deste jeito]
O video é essa logo da apple de fundo, na mihna maquina aparece deste jeito

[image: Quando dou deploy no Heroku fica desse jeito, sem o video]
Quando dou deploy no Heroku fica desse jeito, sem o video

[image: Parte do código onde esta implementado]
Parte do código onde esta implementado

**EDIT: Descobri que o erro estava no id do video, por algum motivo o campo id nao estava dando certo, entao troquei para className e funcionou normalmente.**

**EDIT2: E tambem que o campo opacity no css estava em porcentagem, os navegadores suportam isso, mas quando passa pelo compilador ele nao funciona direito, então troquei para decimal.**

Comment: Editei minha resposta, após baixar seu projeto e verificar o que estava acontecendo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Arquivos estáticos de mídia devem ser importados como se fossem arquivos JavaScript. Por exemplo, o seguinte funciona no build de produção:

```
// nos imports:
import videoFile from '../assets/video.mp4'

// no seu componente:
<video controls muted loop>
    <source src={videoFile} type="video/mp4" />
    Desculpe... seu navegador não suporta vídeos.
</video>
```

Veja mais em https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

### **EDIT:**

O seu vídeo está de fato aparecendo, mas com opacidade de 1%.
Estranhamente, o compilador está mudando o valor original. Veja esta resposta para uma solução. Mude `opacity: 40%;` para `opacity: 0.4;`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58853844/the-opacity-value-was-changed-to-1-after-building-the-reacjs-project

Comment: Encontrei onde estava o erro, não sei porque mas o campo 'id' não estava funcionando direito, então troquei para className e alterei no css tambem para ser uma classe. Agora esta funcionando perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda amigo.

Comment: Não sabia... aparentemente, opacity percentual é suportada pelos navegadores mas não faz parte da especificação. Daí o bundler não leva isso em conta e muda pra 1%. https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-color-3-20180619/#transparency

Comment: Sim, estranho isso, aqui eu deixei em percentual, quando rodava a build no meu PC ficava como deveria estar, mas quando enviava para o Heroku ele não aparecia. Ai fiz oq você falou pra alterar pra decimal e esta perfeito em ambos os casos agora.